# Is it possible to set view on the left side of ImageView using LinearLayouts?

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to place the views like that using nested LinearLayout's? The black rectangle will be an icon which will inform user about current weather (it can be sunny, rainy, cloudy etc) [image]

Comment: yes ... linear layout with horizontal orientation .... you will have to use nested linear layout . i would suggest using constrainlayout

Answer (score 0):

Solved, if someone is curious about code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".hourly_menu"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20°C"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1111 HPA"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11%"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:src="@drawable/day_clear_sky"/>
```